# Populate mongoose across levels and display certain fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  friends: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

User.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'friends',
    populate: { path: 'friends' }
  });
```

The above schema populates the entire User fields for friends array, but for the friends array, I need only name to be populated. How do I limit the fields in the nested level in mongoose.

Comment: its possible to use lookup or just you need to use populate ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi i just need to populate, to pass to frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would first populate `friends` as you have done and then add [select](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) to simply get the fields that you wanted to extract from the `User` model.

```
User.findOne({ name: 'Val' })
  .populate({
    path: 'friends',
    select: ['name', 'fieldName']
  })
```

---

I have added array of elements to demonstrate that you can select more fields that way, in your case it would just be `name`.

Comment: Thank you . It worked perfectly. Although I figured out one more syntax of writing it . 
Adding - (minus) to remove the fields from populating
`User.findOne({ name: 'Val' }) .populate({ path: 'friends', select:"name -id -fieldToRemove" })
`